# How to create and record Multi Data in .net core?

Tags: sql, asp.net-core, foreach

I want to save new data to the table in the .net core structure. This table will be PerfomansID and CategoryID fixed, others incrementing by 1, and it will save these values up to 25 or 100 in the table.

For example, I will say `PerformanceID=45`, `CategoryID=3`, create up to 25 and it will record the SQL.

What kind of structure should I set up?

```
controller:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace KBT.Controllers
{
    public class SalesSeatsController : Controller
    {    
        private readonly ISalesSeatsRepository _salesSeatsRepository;   
        public SalesSeatsController(ISalesSeatsRepository SalesSeatsRepository)
        {
            _salesSeatsRepository = SalesSeatsRepository;
        }

public IActionResult Index()
        {
            object Values = _viFinalSalesSeatsRepository.GetListAll();
            return View(Values);
        }

Table class:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EntityLayer.Concrete
{
    public class SalesSeats
    {
        public int? PerformanceID { get; set; }
        public int? SeatsNumber { get; set; }
        public int? SeatsSalesNumber { get; set; }
        public int? DoorID { get; set; }
        public int? SalesCategoriesID { get; set; }
        public int? SeatsRate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I used to open manual records in excel and save them to SQL. I want to do this from the panel in .net core. I need to set up a for each loop here, but I couldn't succeed.

```
[table][1]
```

Comment: It's had to understand what you want to do. What exactly means "create up to 25 and it will record the SQL"? Please specify the expected output. "I need to set up a for each loop here, but I couldn't succeed" please post what you've tried and describe what exactly does not work as expected.

Comment: My excell page is like as screnshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2y4oK.png
i can add record one row but ı have to create 1 to 25 or 1 to 100 rows and update database.